# django: search by ingredients in a Drinkdatabase

Tags: python, django, filter

I want to create a Django filter, which looks for ingredients, which are included in a drink. However, no other ingredients may be present, only those I enter.

### Example:

- Drink: Gin Tonic
  Ingredients: Gin, Tonic
- Drink: Whiskey Cola
  Ingredients: Whiskey Cola
- Drink: Rum Cola
  Ingredients: Rum, Cola

I admit I have cola and gin and tonic.

The following drinks should come back:

- Gin Tonic

Rum cola isn't coming back because I don't have rum.

How I can do this in Django? I have a database calles TankAllocation. There I enter the ingredients for every tank.

I tryed with Django filter, but there I don't get the correct drinks.

Maybe i can compare the query set of the ingredients of Ingredients table and Tank table and delete duplicate entries, then start a non-equal query with: from django.db.models import Q. But how can I delete duplicate entries in the querieset? both entries should be deletet for a new filter query.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Drink(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    image_path = models.ImageField(upload_to=".\images")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField('Ingredient', through='IngredientRatio', related_name='mischung',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    alcohol = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class IngredientRatio(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey('Ingredient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    drink = models.ForeignKey('Drink', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}: {1} : {2}".format(self.drink.name, self.ingredient.name, self.quantity)

class TankAllocation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
    allocation = models.ForeignKey('Ingredient', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='NULL', related_name='ingredients')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}: {1}".format(self.allocation.name, self.name)
```

Thank you for helping, I'm very new in programming :)))

Comment: "I tryed with Django filter, but there I don't get the correct drinks." - how did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution now :)

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

from django.db.models import Q

from .models import Ingredient, TankAllocation, Drink


def drinkFilter():
    ingredient_list_nq = []
    ingredient_obj_list = Ingredient.objects.all()
    ingredients = [ingredient.name for ingredient in ingredient_obj_list]
    tanks = TankAllocation.objects.all()
    tank_ingredients = [tank.allocation.name for tank in tanks]
    for ingredient in ingredients:
        if ingredient not in tank_ingredients:
            ingredient_list_nq.append(ingredient)

    new_filter = []
    for ingredient in ingredient_list_nq:
        new_filter.append(~Q(ingredient__name=ingredient))
    print(new_filter)
    return new_filter

def get_drinks():
    filter = drinkFilter()
    return Drink.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, filter))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand fully, but something like this should work:

```
ingredients = ['Cola', 'Gin', 'Tonic']
drinks = Drink.objects.filter(ingredient__name__in=ingredients).distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you, but here is the problem, that comes Back whiskey Cola too. But when I don't have Whiskey at home it should not come back ;)In your example only gin and tonic should come back